# SQLite3 in memory datafile

Tags: c, sqlite

Any one know what happens to a in memory datafile when the process is forked and the parent process closes the in memory datafile. My understanding was that it should be in scope in the child process.

Comment: More information would be helpful. Details about your environment, some code, some observations about what happens when running that code. http://www.sqlite.org/c_interface.html recommends against the approach of forking after opening the db.

Comment: Running it on a ubuntu 10.10, I'm using GDB for the debugger. Getting a segmentation fault. The persistent connection are fine. I was doing a bit of further reading and don't think its possible.

Answer (score 0):

When a process forks, the memory of the new process is completely independent.

An in-memory database does not have any externally visible effects (like files), so what you get are two independent databases, and closing one does not affect the other.

Please note that a *temporary* database (empty file name) is not the same as an in-memory database (file name `:memory:`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am inserting a number of records to the in-memory database before the fork. Subsequent to the fork, am I right in saying that the child process should have a copy of the in-memory database, with the inserted records. If so, it doesn't happen as I am getting segmentation fault.